# Braintree sub-merchant account creation

Tags: php, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am not able to create a sub-merchant account in Braintree with the business address outside US. I am using the Braintree sandbox account and PHP SDK. I have successfully created a master merchant account. When I try to create sub-merchant account with the Australian business address, Braintree responds with below error:

> Individual region is invalid.

However, I am able to create sub-merchant account if I use the US address similar to that mentioned in Braintree documentation.
Documentation url:  https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/onboarding/php

My address parameters:

```
    'business' => [
    'legalName' => 'Jane\'s Ladders',
    'dbaName' => 'Jane\'s Ladders',
    'taxId' => '98-7654321',
    'address' => [
      'streetAddress' => '6 10 Smith Street',
      'locality' => 'NEUTRAL BAY',
      'region' => 'NSW',
      'postalCode' => '02055'
    ]
  ]
```

Can't I use address outside the US to create sub-merchant account?

Comment: Please update your post and include a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You cannot use sub-merchants outside the US. From the [Braintree developer documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/overview#compatibility):

> Both the master merchant and sub-merchants must be domiciled in the US and receive funding in USD

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the exact statement in documentation that cleared my confusion.